# ansible-playbook Execution order

Tags: ansible

This yml file is mainly used to install mysql, but I found that the yml file execution order is a bit strange.

Why is the handler implementation later than the restart mysqld task? why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9div.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyImp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted the complete code. Handler section is missing. You might want to find out where does the "Reload service" [handler](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change) come from.

To answer your question

> Why is the handler implementation later than the restart mysqld task?

The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change)  is clear about it

> These ‘notify’ actions are triggered at the end of each block of tasks in a play, and will only be triggered once even if notified by multiple different tasks.